# How can I get a PDF data from firebase storage - Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to get a pdf file data into my code from firebase/google storage.

Here is what I've done so far

```
from google.cloud import storage
from firebase import firebase

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://test.firebaseio.com/')
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('test.appspot.com')
blob = bucket.blob('Motivation_Letter.pdf')

blob.download_as_string()
```

I get this kind of output. How can I make it readable?

```
b'%PDF-1.7\r\n%\xb5\xb5\xb5\xb5\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-US) /StructTreeRoot 15 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 44 0 R/ViewerPreferences 45 0 R>>\r\nendobj\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>\r\nendobj\r\n3 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R/F2 9 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS7 7 0 R/GS8 8 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>\r\nendobj\r\n4 0 obj\r\n<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 3283>>\r\nstream\r\nx\x9c\xb5\\[O\xdcH\x16~G\xe2?\xd4c{\x97v\\\xbe[BH\x81$\xb3\x8c\x16)+\xc8\x8eF3\xfb`h\x87xc\x1a\xb6\xdb$\xdb\xf9\xf5[\xe7\xd4\xdd\xae\xa2![\x8c\x14\x04n\xb7\xab\xea\\\xbe\xf3\x9d\x8b\x87\xbc\xf9H\x8e\x8f\xdf\\\x9c\x9d\xbf#\xc9\xc9\t9}wF\xfesx\x90\xc4\t\xfc\xd7\xd0\x94$\xa4d?\xab&%\x9b\xee\xf0\xe0\xb7\xbf\x90\xf5\xe1\xc1\xe9\xd5\xe1\xc1\x9b\x0f\x94\xb0\x0f\xae>\x1f\x1ePvSB(\xa9\xd28I\x0bR%u\x9cW\xe4\xea\x8e\xdd\xf4\xcbeEn\xb7\xec\x81\xe4\x16\xff\xaa\xc5_\xbf\x1c\x1e\xfc\xb1x\x17-\x9bE\xd7n\xa2e\xb9 ....... '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save this data as in PDF file using this type of concept.

```
""" PDF DATA VAR """
DATA_FROM_FIREBASE=b'%PDF-1.7\r\n%\xb5\xb5\xb5\xbype/Cat ....... '  

pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf', 'wb')     
pdfFileObj.write(DATA_FROM_FIREBASE)    
pdfFileObj.close()
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, but is there a way to do so without creating a new file, cause I need to work on that data?
 n this way, I am fetching from storage, then saving to a file and then calling that file and working on the data. Thank you in advance!

Comment: PyPDF2 is one of the best option because many help/example presents in online.
you can install using this link : https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/